# Excel 2013 crashing / hanging

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, crash

I have a workbook with lots of VBA code in it. I has been crashing for several weeks now, usually after I run some of the code.

As a result of all the crashing I started making a backups of the file to OneDrive and downloaded a CodeCleaner utility. On a file crash I have been able to use a combination of "Open and Repair" and then clean the code, at which point the environment would be stable until the next shutdown.

I kind of suspect some combination of OneDrive and some Trust issue somewhere as part of the problem, but now I am seeing a new one.

On running Open and Repair I now see the program hangs and the Task Manager shows it it waiting on what appears to be a print spooler of some sort.

[image]

Any ideas??

#### UPDATE

1. running this locally in a folder location that is part of VBA Trust
2. shutdown meaning either file close or computer reboot
3. have imported the code modules to a new workbook, still happens. Code is large, about 180 modules/classes. Have reinstalled excel 2013 twice

Comment: Do you have any long loops, or particularly intensive operations in there? VBA is single threaded, any intensive operations will lock up the main thread and you'll effectively see a crash until it completes or something kills it, under the assumption it has stopped responding.

Comment: Are you opening this online or downloading it before running the code? When you say "*would be stable until the next shutdown*", do you mean shutdown the computer or close the file? Have you attempted copying the content to a new file (not *save as*) to see if the file is damaged? How about trying on another PC to see if your installation is corrupt?

Comment: @CharlieRB. Good questions! See edit at end of post